# Laravel query how to make 3 data from database become 1 in view table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, group-by, sum

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGoel.png)

i have 1 model and have 3 row data  , right now the table look like this :

[view table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYr1d.png)

i want the table view will look like this :

[table view 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtsUt.png)

what query should i use to make 3 data become 1 by its id and created_at,
my query right now is 
`$query = TimesheetsDetail::with('operator_proyek.operator','operator_proyek.unit.tipe_unit')->where('timesheets_id',$timesheets->id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want aggregation:

```
select operator_id, sum(durasi_jam_kerja), sum(durasi_jam_lembur), sum(durasi_jam_standby)
from t
group by operator_id;
```